# Yocto compilation fails constantly with different errors

Tags: git, yocto, realsense

i'm trying to create a custom Yocto image adding Realsense layer, for IMX8 but every time I build with bitbake, I get git errors.

https://github.com/SolidRun/meta-solidrun-arm-imx8

https://github.com/IntelRealSense/meta-intel-realsense/tree/hardknott

> ERROR: arm-compute-library-21.08-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/arm-computelibrary-imx.git;protocol=https;branch=lf-5.10.72_2.2.0'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

But if I apply *git clone* I can check the command is fine and the git link is fine too. What is the origin from these problems?

EDIT: other errors got after apply bitbake -c clean:

> opencv-4.5.2.imx-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://github.com/opencv/opencv.git;name=opencv;branch=master;protocol=https'. Unable to fetch URL from any source
>
> armnn-onnx-protobuf-1.6.0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'git://github.com/onnx/onnx.git;branch=rel-1.6.0;protocol=https'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

protocol=https on the onnx line has been added by me because the link works fine and I though that https could solve the problem.

Comment: Have you a proxy ?

Comment: No. I have tried to configure git with "git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://". And when I try with git clone command all works fine, but in the bb file with bitbake doesn't work.